# Parsing a CSV file using shell

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk

My shell is a bit rusty so I would greatly appreciate some help in parsing the following data.

Each row in the input file contains data separated by comma.

```
[name, record_timestamp, action, field_id, field_name, field_value, number_of_fields]
```

The rows are instructions to create or update information about persons. So for example the first line says that the person John Smith will be created and that the following 6 rows will contain information about him.

The field_id number always represent the same field.

**input.csv**

```
John Smith,2017-03-03 11:56:02,create,,,,6
,,,,1,BIRTH_DATE,1985-02-16,,
,,,,2,BIRTH_CITY,Portland,,
,,,,3,SEX,Male,,
,,,,5,CITY,Seattle,,
,,,,7,EMPLOYER,Microsoft,,
,,,,9,MARRIED,Yes,,
Susan Anderson,2017-03-01 12:09:36,create,,,,8
,,,,1,BIRTH_DATE,1981-09-12,,
,,,,2,BIRTH_CITY,San Diego,,
,,,,3,SEX,Female,,
,,,,5,CITY,Palo Alto,,
,,,,7,EMPLOYER,Facebook,,
,,,,8,SALARY,5612,,
,,,,9,MARRIED,No,,
,,,,10,TELEPHONE,5107586290,,
Brad Bradly,2017-02-29 09:15:12,update,,,,3
,,,,3,SEX,Male,,
,,,,7,EMPLOYER,Walmart,,
,,,,9,MARRIED,No,,
Sarah Wilson,2017-02-28 16:21:39,update,,,,5
,,,,2,BIRTH_CITY,Miami,,
,,,,3,SEX,Female,,
,,,,7,EMPLOYER,Disney,,
,,,,8,SALARY,5110,,
,,,,9,MARRIED,Yes,,
```

I want to parse each of these persons into comma separated strings that looks like this:

```
name,birth date,birth city,sex,employer,salary,marrage status,record_timestamp
```

but we should only output such a string if both the fields **birth date and birth city** or both the fields **employer and salary** are available for that person. Otherwise just leave it empty (see example below).

Given our input above the output should then be

```
John Smith,1985-02-16,Portland,Male,,,Yes,2017-03-03 11:56:02
Susan Anderson,1981-09-12,San Diego,Female,Facebook,5612,No,2017-03-01 12:09:36
Sarah Wilson,,,Female,Disney,5110,Yes,2017-02-28 16:21:39
```

I've figured out that I should probably do something along the following lines. But then I cannot figure out how to implement an inner loop or if there is some other way to proceed.

```
#!/bin/bash
IFS=','
cat test.txt | while read -a outer
do
    echo ${outer[0]}
    #...
done
```

Thanks in advance for any advice!

Comment: The CSV file format is such a loose standard to begin with, and it's a lot more complicated than simply splitting on commas. Why not use a scripting language with a proper CSV module? They *all* have them.

Comment: And if indeed your input is completely regular, an Awk script would be a lot simpler, more readable, and significantly faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A UNIX shell is an environment from which to call UNIX tools (and manipulate files and processes) with a language to sequence those calls. [It is NOT a tool to manipulate text](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice).

The standard UNIX tool to manipulate text is awk:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    numFlds=split("name BIRTH_DATE BIRTH_CITY SEX EMPLOYER SALARY MARRIED timestamp",nr2name)
    FS=OFS=","
}
$1 != "" {
    prtRec()
    rec["name"] = $1
    rec["timestamp"] = $2
    next
}
{ rec[$6] = $7 }
END { prtRec() }

function prtRec(        fldNr) {
    if ( ((rec["BIRTH_DATE"] != "") && (rec["BIRTH_CITY"] != "")) ||
         ((rec["EMPLOYER"] != "") && (rec["SALARY"] != "")) ) {
        for (fldNr=1; fldNr<=numFlds; fldNr++) {
            printf "%s%s", rec[nr2name[fldNr]], (fldNr<numFlds ? OFS : ORS)
        }
    }
    delete rec
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
John Smith,1985-02-16,Portland,Male,Microsoft,,Yes,2017-03-03 11:56:02
Susan Anderson,1981-09-12,San Diego,Female,Facebook,5612,No,2017-03-01 12:09:36
Sarah Wilson,,Miami,Female,Disney,5110,Yes,2017-02-28 16:21:39
```

Any time you have records consisting of name+value data like you do, the approach that results in by far the simplest, clearest, most robust, and easiest to enhance/debug code is to first populate an array (`rec[]` above) containing the values indexed by the names. Once you have that array it's trivial to print and/or manipulate the contents by their names.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Very helpful! AWK is the way to go! :)

Answer (score 1):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
awk -F, 'function pr(a) {if(!(7 in a && 8 in a)) a[7]=a[8]=""; 
                         if(!(1 in a && 2 in a)) a[1]=a[2]=""; 
                         for(i=0;i<=10;i++) printf "%s,",a[i]; 
                         printf "%s\n", a["ts"]} 
         NR>1 && $1!="" {pr(a); delete a}
         $1!=""         {a[0]=$1; a["ts"]=$2} 
         $1==""         {a[$5]=$7}
         END            {pr(a)}' file
```

this should cover the general case, and conditioned fields. You may want to filter out the other fields you don't need.

This will print for your input

```
John Smith,1985-02-16,Portland,Male,,Seattle,,,,Yes,,2017-03-03 11:56:02
Susan Anderson,1981-09-12,San Diego,Female,,Palo Alto,,Facebook,5612,No,5107586290,2017-03-01 12:09:36
Brad Bradly,,,Male,,,,,,No,,2017-02-29 09:15:12
Sarah Wilson,,,Female,,,,Disney,5110,Yes,,2017-02-28 16:21:39
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Indeed, AWK is the way to go! :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `awk` or something like

```
while IFS=, read -r name timestamp action f_id f_name f_value nr_fields; do
   if [ -n "${name}" ]; then
      # proces startrecord, store the fields you need for the next line
   else
      # process next record
   fi
done < test.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Avoid IFS hacks like the plague.  They are ugly stuff.

Play with the -d option to **read** to specify the comma as delimiter.